# Can't get ActiveRecordSectionHandler to work properly

Tags: c#, nhibernate, activerecord, app-config, castle-activerecord

I have the following config set up in my test project:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="activerecord" type="Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Config.ActiveRecordSectionHandler, Castle.ActiveRecord" />
    ...
  </configSections>
  ...
  <activerecord>
    <config>
      <add key="connection.provider" value="(MyNamespace).Tests.Helpers.TestingConnectionProvider, (MyNamespace).Tests" />
      <add key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect" />
      <add key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SQLiteDriver" />
      <add key="connection.connection_string" value="Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;" />
      <add key="show_sql" value="true" />
      <add key="query.substitutions" value="true=1;false=0" />
      <add key="proxyfactory.factory_class" value="NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle"/>
    </config>
  </activerecord>
  ...
</configuration>
```

I have also added the nhibernate prefix to the keys, as some documentation has suggested.  My connection provider looks like:

```
public class TestingConnectionProvider : DriverConnectionProvider
{
    public static IDbConnection Connection { get; private set; }

    public override IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return Connection ?? (Connection = base.GetConnection());
    }
}
```

When I try to run my test:

```
[TestClass]
public class PersistenceTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CanBuildSchemaInMemory()
    {
        if (File.Exists("SqlCreate.sql")) File.Delete("SqlCreate.sql");
        ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(typeof(IPermissionsManager).Assembly, new ActiveRecordSectionHandler());
        ActiveRecordStarter.GenerateCreationScripts("CreateNew.sql");
        Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists("SqlCreate.sql"));
    }
}
```

... I get a failure that indicates I am not properly set up.  However, if I change the `ActiveRecordSectionHandler()` out for:

```
InPlaceConfigurationSource.Build(DatabaseType.MsSqlServer2008, "Server=localhost, Initial Catalog=Permissions, Integrated Security=SSPI;")
```

... this works, so clearly the problem is with my configuration.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this was based off a couple of boneheaded things I did, and a genuine lack of understanding on some other things.

Boneheaded thing #1: I was generating a file other than the name I was looking for.  Nice job, Jeremy.

Boneheaded thing #2: I had extra namespace elements in my config file; it's not `NHibernate.Dialect.NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect`, it's just `NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect`.

Genuine misunderstanding: I thought the `ActiveRecordSectionHandler` was meant to be instantiated; turns out, I needed the static property of `Instance` to work.  So what it should have looked like is:

```
ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(typeof(IPermissionsManager).Assembly, ActiveRecordSectionHandler.Instance);
```

Voila! the test passes.